# MKDIR doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, upload, mkdir

For some reason all folders created dynamically using my PHP upload script get permission 1354 and then it's not possible to save files inside them.

```
if(!file_exists($options['uploadDir']) && !is_dir($options['uploadDir'])
&& mkdir($options['uploadDir'], 0750, true))
{
    $this->data['hasWarnings'] = true;
    $this->data['warnings'] = "A new directory was created in " .
    realpath($options['uploadDir']);
}
if(!is_writable($options['uploadDir'])) 
    @chmod($options['uploadDir'], 0750);
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is this your actual code? 750 in base 10 is 1356 in base 8, so it looks very much like you put `750` in your code somewhere instead of `0750`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check parameters of your http server especially the profile of the user running it and the default user profile of the system. There may be a "umask" set somewhere forcing another permission.

You can try to change the umask with a php command [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php).

Also you can check the permission of the parent folders and also check the ownership of your folder.